# For a twice differential function $f(x)$, find all $f$ such that $f(B_t)$ is a martingale, where $B_t$ is Brownian Motion.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-integrals

I used Ito's lemma and came up with:

$\require{enclose}
\enclose{horizontalstrike} {f_t = \dfrac{f_{xx}}{2}}$

where $f = f(B_t)$

How do I proceed further with this differential equation? Can it be solved without losing generality?

Edit: I realized that $f_t = 0$ since $f$ is independent of $B_t$. So the equation boils down to

$\dfrac {\partial d^2}{\partial x^2}f(B_t) = 0$

How does one solve this kind of differential equation. Note: Here the 'x' implies derivative w.r.t the $B_t$ variable.

Comment: If $f''(x)=0$ then $f(x)=ax+b$ for some fixed $(a,b)$. Is this your question?

Comment: Is that all that is required? All $f$'s linear in $B_t$ will be martingales? I got that answer but not sure if its complete.

Comment: What would be missing?

Comment: Hmm. You're right. Perhaps I was just over thinking it. The problem is there is always some last step I miss out on which costs me the full score on these questions. Thanks.

Comment: @Did can you check this question out https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338392/find-constants-a-b-and-a-differential-equation-satistfied-by-px-such-that-x I'm missing something basic but not sure what.