# For $X_t = t^aP(\frac{B_t}{t^b})$ to be martingale, find constants a,b and a differential equation satistfied by $P(\frac{B_t}{t^b})$

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Here $B_t$ is Brownian motion and $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n, n \ge 1$

Assuming $f(t,B_t) = X_t$, I used Ito lemma and used $f_t + f_{xx} = 0$ to equate the drift part of the SDE to $0$. So I get something like this:

$$ \frac{a}{t}P(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) - \frac{b}{t^{b+1}}P'(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) + \frac{1}{t^{2b}}P''(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) = 0 $$

because $$ f_t = at^{a-1}P(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) - b\frac{t^a}{t^{b+1}}P'(\frac{B_t}{t^b})$$ and $$f_{xx} = \frac{t^a}{ t^{2b}}P''(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) $$

What should a and b be from this equation so that $X_t = t^a P(\dfrac{B_t}{t^b})$ is a martingale?

Earlier I tried using the general form of a polynomial like this

$P(x) = c_n x^n + c_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \dots c_1 x + c_0$

and tried differentiating that. But it gave me extremely complicated terms when I differentiate it twice.

Edit: I further simpified the DE as follows:

$$at^{2b -1}P(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) - b t^{b-1}P'(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) + P''(\frac{B_t}{t^b}) = 0  $$

A trivial solution would be that the polynomial $P$ is identically zero.

Another solution is that $a=0, b=1$ along with $P' = 0$ Is that all?

The second part of the question asks what $X_t$ looks like for $n = 2,3,4$. Shouldn't $n$ be equal to $1$ for $P' = 0$?

Guys, anyone? I am probably doing this wrong but can't figure out what exactly.

Comment: updated the question with new information.

Comment: I´ve seen it and I´ve deleted my previous comment.

Comment: any hints on how to proceed?

Comment: Not from my side. You have to wait till somebody else has an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the partial derivative wrt. $t$ you missed one inner derivative
$$
f_t(t,u)=at^{a-1}P(t^{-b}u)-bt^{a-b-1}uP'(t^{-b}u)
$$
so that the drift term in the Ito formula is
$$
0=f_t+\tfrac12f_{uu}=t^{a-1}(aP(t^{-b}u)-bt^{-b}uP'(t^{-b}u)+\tfrac12t^{1-2b}P''(t^{-b}u))
$$
As $t$ and $u$ are independent, either $P''=0$ or $b=\frac12$. In the more interesting second case setting $w=t^{-b}u$ gives the equation
$$
0=2aP(w)-wP'(w)+P''(w)
$$
In the highest degree coefficient of the degree $n$ polynomial one gets 
$$
0=2ac_n-nc_n
$$
so that $a=\frac{n}2$. As also $0=2ac_{n-1}-(n-1)c_{n-1}$ one gets $c_{n-1}=0$ (and then $c_{n-3}=0$, $c_{n-5}=0$,...). With $c_n=1$ the other coefficients are uniquely determined.

- For $n=2$ then $0=2c_0+2c_2$ giving $f(t,B_t)=B_t^2-t$.
- For $n=3$ further $0=3c_1-c_1+6c_3\implies c_1=-3$ and $0=3c_0+2c_2$ so that $c_0=0$ and $$f(t,B_t)=t^{3/2}((B_t/\sqrt{t})^3-3(B_t/\sqrt{t}))=B_t^3-3tB_t.$$

...

Comment: The solution seems correct, but I still don't quite get why $t$ and $u$ being independent implies the $P'' = 0$ or $b = \frac{1}{2}$. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Because then also $t$ and $w$ are independent. In $0=aP(w)-bwP'(w)-\frac12t^{1-2b}P''(w)$ and $b\ne \frac12$ the variation of $t$, for instance inserting $t=1$ and $t=2$, leads to $0=aP(w)-bwP'(w)$ and $0=P''(w)$ simultaneously. Only $b=\frac12$ leads to a non-trivial ODE for $P$.

Comment: why p'' = 0 is sufficient?

Comment: It is not sufficient, one would have to analyze it further, then it leads to the trivial solution $P(x)=x$, $a=b$. This is already contained in the other solution class, thus no further explored in the answer.

Comment: oh, my question is that why t and u are independent implies that p''=0 or t=1/2

Comment: After the substitution the remaining equation is $$aP(w)-bwP(w)+\frac12t^{1-2b}P''(w)=0$$ which has to be valid for all pairs $(t,w)$, $t>0$. The first two terms do not depend on $t$, thus the last one also has to be in the end independent of $t$. This is achieved by either $b=\frac12$ or $P''(w)=0$. Note that in this whole computation, $t,u,w$ are real variables, there is no randomness involved.